# Crash only caused since iOS13 which I can't reproduce

Tags: swift, crash, crashlytics, ios13

Crashlytics has been registering this crash which I can't seem to reproduce. I have looked at the code and I can't find anything that could cause this crash.

What is stranger is that it has only been showing up since the release of iOS13. All the crashes are on devices that have iOS13 installed. Prior to iOS13 this crash never happend. This particular piece of code has been there for over two years.

Can anyone come up with what might be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Spotted by                     0x104eaf2c0 partial apply for closure #1 in CitiesListViewController.tableSections.didset + 35 (CitiesListViewController.swift:35)
1  Spotted by                     0x104ee8508 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () (<compiler-generated>)
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b48b1610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b48b2184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1b489535c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 996
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1b4b623c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1b4b5d3b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2004
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1b4b5c8bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 464
8  GraphicsServices               0x1be9c8328 GSEventRunModal + 104
9  UIKitCore                      0x1b8bf26d4 UIApplicationMain + 1936
10 Spotted by                     0x104e95c00 main + 21 (SBLAppDelegate.swift:21)
11 libdyld.dylib                  0x1b49e7460 start + 4
```

This is the code I have (line 35 is self.tableView.reloadData()):

```
typealias TableData = [SectionData]
typealias SectionData = [String: [Any]]

private var tableSections = TableData() {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

The datasource code:

```
func setupData() {
    let sortPurchasedCitiesByAlpha: (CityID, CityID) -> Bool = { (cityId1, cityId2) -> Bool in
        guard
            let city1 = CitiesManager.shared.city(withId: cityId1),
            let city2 = CitiesManager.shared.city(withId: cityId2)
            else { assertionFailure("missing cities?"); return false }
        return city1.name.lowercased() <= city2.name.lowercased()
    }
    var sections = TableData()
    // reverse to show most recent purchase first
    let allPurchased = Array(CitiesManager.shared.purchasedCityIds())
    var purchased: [CityID] = []
    let lastUsedCityId = Defaults[.lastUsedCity]
    if let lastUsedCityId = lastUsedCityId {
        // put last used first
        let rest = Array(allPurchased.removing(lastUsedCityId))
        let restSorted = rest.sorted(by: sortPurchasedCitiesByAlpha)
        if allPurchased.contains(lastUsedCityId) { // may have been deleted
            purchased.append(lastUsedCityId)
        }
        purchased.append(contentsOf: restSorted)
    } else {
        purchased = allPurchased.sorted(by: sortPurchasedCitiesByAlpha)
    }
    installedSectionPresent = !purchased.isEmpty
    if installedSectionPresent {
        sections.append(["Installed": purchased])
    }
    let continents = CitiesManager.shared.allContinentsOfNotPurchasedCities()
    continents.forEach { continent in
        let cityIds = CitiesManager.shared.cityIdsNotPurchased(forContinent: continent)
        sections.append([continent: cityIds])
    }
    tableSections = sections
}
```

Comment: Hi @FredFlinstone what's your XCode version?

Comment: Hi @FredFlinstone
can you add your tableView dataSource code to your question?!

Comment: @EmreCiftci Current version is Xcode 11.1. But last App Store release was done using Xcode 10.2.1

Comment: @Mor4eza I just added the datasourcecode

Comment: @FredFlinstone did you fix it? I have the same problem with iOS 13.3 only, and it can't be reproduced.

Comment: Hi Soufian, the accepted answer did fix it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setter might be called before the whole view hierarchy is created.

try

```
private var tableSections = TableData() {
    didSet {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView?.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would have to make a new release to check if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I bet that there isn't a way around.

Comment: I'm sure there isn't. I'm just curious about why this didn't cause crashes prior to iOS 13. Maybe the way the hierarchy is created changed. Anyway, thanks and I'll upvote if this solves the crash.

Comment: You should upvote the answer, if you are grateful. its a way to say thanks, not a payment for delivered services. That said: you are welcome not to vote on it.

Comment: it's not my way of thinking. it's decency.

Comment: What would be decent is not just assuming that anyone on this platform knows all protocols. I never knew that upvoting is expected for all answers and not only for correct answers. Enjoy your up- and downvote